# node.js fork function and passing arguments to child-process

Tags: node.js

I pass arguments when create chlid-processes

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
        var new_worker_env = {};
        new_worker_env["WORKER_NAME"] = "worker" + i;

        var new_worker = cluster.fork(new_worker_env);
    }
}
```

and then try to read it in childs:

```
if ( process.env["WORKER_NAME"] != undefined ) instance.name = process.env["WORKER_NAME"];
```

but this var isn't exist, why?

Node v0.8.8

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems to work for me on Windows, Node.js version 0.8.8

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
    os      = require('os');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < os.cpus().length; i++) {
        var new_worker_env = {};

        new_worker_env["WORKER_NAME"] = "worker" + i;

        var new_worker = cluster.fork(new_worker_env);
    }
} else {
    console.log(process.env['WORKER_NAME']);
}
```

outputs:

```
worker0
worker1
```

Comment: But for me (I've made new app same as yours) it doesn't work, output is eight "undefined". What it may be? I work under Unix x64 (freebsd)

Comment: I found reason, when I use this line of code it doesn't work, why?: var server_store = new (require("socket.io-clusterhub"));

Comment: Its because the socket.io-clusterhub dependency clusterhub, https://github.com/fent/clusterhub, overwrites the cluster.fork method and does not pass the env to the original method. A workaround would be to edit /node_modules/clusterhub/lib/fork.js where it over-rides the cluster.fork method to pass the env or file a bug report with the clusterhub project above and wait for them to fix it